# Open Custom ListView Menu with ImageView OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I'm new to android studio and I have an issue where I can't get my custom listview menu to open when an ImageView is clicked. Here is my code that I have at the minute. I have tried to get a toggle to work but nothing I do helps!

**MainActivity**

```
        final List<Nav> navList= new ArrayList<Nav>();
        navList.add(new Nav("Profile"));
        navList.add(new Nav("Feed"));
        navList.add(new Nav("Maps"));
        navList.add(new Nav("Most Popular"));
        navList.add(new Nav("Settings"));
        navList.add(new Nav("Report a Bug"));

        ArrayAdapter<Nav> navadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Nav>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, navList);
        final ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(left_drawer);
        lv.setAdapter(navadapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int itemPosition = position;

                switch(itemPosition) {

                    case 0:
                        Intent menuItem = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfileActivity.class);
                        startActivity(menuItem);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        menuItem = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(menuItem);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        menuItem = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserMapActivity.class);
                        startActivity(menuItem);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        menuItem = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserMapActivity.class);
                        startActivity(menuItem);
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        menuItem = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(menuItem);
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        menuItem = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserMapActivity.class);
                        startActivity(menuItem);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        navbut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                customListView1.toggle();
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept playing around with the code and the below worked:

```
navbut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });
```